# Commandline installation of AspectJ

Tags: aspectj

I would like to install AspectJ from within a shell script. However, the installation document has instructions only for GUI based installer. Is there a way to install AspectJ from commandline?

http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/downloads.php#install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you ensure a directory exists you can use java -jar:

```
mkdir ~/aspectj182
java -jar aspectj-1.8.2.jar -to ~/aspectj182
```